# "Invalid object name" exception when trying to add collection object of an entity - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have my C# Model classes generated from SQL using ADO.net Entity Model. 
I created 2 additional classes which are not generated by ADO which have 1 to many relationship.

The class definition is below:

**LISToxPatient**

```
[Table("LISToxPatient")]
public class LISToxPatient
{
    public LISToxPatient()
    {
        LISResults = new HashSet<LISResult>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long LISToxPatientID { get; set; }
    public long? PatientID { get; set; }
    public long? NetworkID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Prescriber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ResultSummary { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Specimen { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LISResult> LISResults { get; set; }

}
```

**LIS Result**

```
[TableName("LISResult")]
public class LISResult
{
    [Key]
    public long LISResultID { get; set; }
    public long LISToxPatientID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Remark { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Compound { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CreateBy { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDT { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateDT { get; set; }
    public bool? Deleted { get; set; } = false;
    public virtual LISToxPatient LISToxPatient { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to add "LISToxPatient" object which holds a collection of "LISResult" entities, I get an error which says:

> "Invalid object name dbo.LISResults".

I can see that see error is due to the EF trying to find pluralized table name which doesn't exist in db but all my other table classes use the pluralized table name convention. I tried to add this line

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

but still get the same error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Don;t remove conventiion. Add `Table` attribute as you already did for the other table.

Comment: I have already decorated the other class with that attribute. I didn't copy it above.